# CSS : span in left with fixed width, span in right with fixed width, the center table fills up rest of the space

Tags: css

markup :

```
<div>
    <span class="left"></span>
    <table></table>
    <span class="right"></span>
</div>
```

Desired output :

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      |                                                          |      |
|.left |                                                          |.right|
|      |                                                          |      |
|      |                       table                              |      |
|      |                    dynamic width                         |      | 
|width |                                                          |width |
| 1em  |                                                          | 1em  |
|      |                                                          |      |
|      |                                                          |      |
|      |                                                          |      |
|      |                                                          |      |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The solutions i saw on other answers just don't work when center element is a table.

Comment: That's not how you use spans really...

Comment: well, I'm not using spans for containing other elements, so I think I've used them appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float`, also using `span` as a container is not a good idea. Instead use `div`. Also put your `table` inside a `div`:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
.main {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right</div>
  <div class="main">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is `display:block;` and `position`. Actually, you should use div in this case and we can omit `display:block` if you use div

```
.left{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.right{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    display:block;
    width:20px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

div{
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

table{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M887N/2/)

Here I display borders to give you a view on the widths

Comment: good answer, but I accepted NOX's answer since it doesn't use absolute positioning

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve your markup you can use the `calc()` property.

You could float left your `<span>`and the table, and set the width of the table as this:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse; width:calc(100% - 2em); float:left;}
```

With this solution, the table is really 100% width, instead a background trick.

Here's a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jPuSu/1/).

I'm agree with the comments saying that use `<span>` it's a bad idea, but... I think you have your reasons ;)

Comment: good answer for 2020, but here in 2013, people still use IE 6 :P

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha More than 1%? [Perhaps in China](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) :p